# ADT not accessing other class, constructors not working

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a Node class and I want the default to be all 0's and null and then when I call the node class with constructors i want to set them. and with the code I have set now I just keep getting
symbol:   method Node(int,int,java.lang.String)
location: variable n1 of type Node
I don't understand what's wrong with my default constructor cause it will only work when I delete it.

```
class Node{
  private int ticks;
  private int jobId;
  private String name;
  private Node next;



 public Node(){
   next = null;
   ticks = 0;
   jobId = 0;
   name = " ";

  }

  public Node(int t,int j, String name){
    ticks = t;
    jobId = j;
    name = name;

  }

  //sets next to node
  public void setNext(Node next){
   next = next ;

  }

}//end class node
```

MAIN---------------------------------------------------------

```
public class lab3{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  //Open File
  File file = new File("p3.dat");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(file);



   int jobId = storeJobIdNum(in);
   int ticks = storeTicks(in);
   String name = storeName(in);

     Node n1 = new Node();
   n1.Node(ticks,jobId,name);

   jobId = storeJobIdNum(in);
   ticks = storeTicks(in);
   name = storeName(in);
 //  String line = in.nextLine();
  // String name = line;

 //System.out.println(jobId+" "+num+" "+numTicks);

//  n1.setNode(,,);



}//end main

public static String storeName(Scanner in){
  String name = in.next();
  System.out.println(name);
  return name;
}

public static int storeJobIdNum(Scanner in){
  int num = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println(num);
  return num;
}

public static int storeTicks(Scanner in){
  int num = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println(num);
  return num;
}

}//end class
```

p3.dat looks like ==>    1 4 name 
and has a few lines that differ.

Comment: You seem to have a stray `set` before Node's default constructor.

Comment: ya wasn't supposed to be there @JeffreyBosboom

Comment: You can't call a constructor after creating the object.

Comment: @immibis please elaborate because if your talking about-----------------                Node n1 = new Node();
 n1.Node(ticks,jobId,name);            ------------   i dont understand why i cant do that? i want to create n1 which at first has values of 0 and null then i want to change them

Comment: @cmehmen the whole point of constructors is they run when the object is created. Are you creating an object in `n1.Node(ticks, jobId, name);`? No? Then you can't call a constructor.

Comment: A constructor is responsible for the instantiation of an object. It is defined to have the same name as the class.  Once the object is created by calling the constructor Node n1 = new Node( ); , it is no longer allowed to be instantiated "again", if you will.  Instead, you have to change its fields using setter methods.

Comment: Node n1 = new Node(ticks,jobId,name); yeah ok your right! then if want to change this i could now with like n1.set(x,x,x).  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the object is created, you won't be able to invoke another constructor with it. Instead, create a method that takes care of changing the fields.

Put this as your method call to set the attributes:

```
Node n1 = new Node();
n1.set(ticks,jobId,name);
```

And then in Node, use this instead of another constructor:

```
public void set(int t,int j, String name){
    this.ticks = t;
    this.jobId = j;
    this.name = name;
}
```

You'll generally hear these be called "setter" methods.

Comment: Or use `Node n1 = new Node(ticks, jobId, name);`